# Replacing Specific Text in a page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to replace a specific snippet of text inside a paragraph. I am just  trying to replace the phone number. The code inside the body i am unable to access due to it being pushed to us via our partner.

> To see what options are available please contact a lodging specialist
>   via calling 866.264.1842.

I have tried

```
$("body").html(
    $("body").html().replace(/866.264.1842/g,'888.888.4754') );
```

This works however it breaks other code on our page and makes our calendar picker not work. Is there a way just to do this with css. I have access to the CSS but not the JS that is running on the page.

Comment: can you share the html?

Comment: Is there anyway to wrap the phone number in an element with an id for easy editing/

Comment: You replace the whole body and loose all interactivity. You will need to attach your datepicker again. You may be better off targeting specific elements.

Comment: your code should work fine unless there's something else happening after you replace. check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/d9oourhn/

Comment: mask ur . in regex with \ so it becomes \.
. is matching any char in regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume the phone number is in a div which ID is "contact". Then you have to do that:

```
$("#contact").html($("#contact").html().replace(/866.264.1842/g,'888.888.4754'))
```

That way you don't remove the DOM modifications made by your calendar picker javascript code.

Comment: This worked without throwing any errors. The ID element is what I was missing. The date picker works perfectly still.

Answer (score 0):

I have rewritten a function for this, hopefully this should work for you

```
function replaceDOMText(str, replaceWith) {
    $('body:contains(' + str + ')').contents().each(function() {
        if (this.nodeType == 3) {
            $(this).parent().html(function(_, oldValue) {
                return oldValue.replace(RegExp(str, "g"), replaceWith);
            })
        }
    });
}


// Call like this
replaceDOMText("866.264.1842", "888.888.4754" );
```

Play with this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bzk85z68/3/)

Comment: So say I had another phone number I needed to change I could add another replaceDOMText under the first one correct? ie replaceDOMText("866.123.456", "888.888.4754" ); and so on.

Comment: I just Tried this and it through this error "Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/." also it breaks my date picker.

Comment: XMLhttp error should not be due to this. Is there any other JS error? Was your date picker working fine without my code?